# Mock assert function called before exception is thrown

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to unit test some code using Mock. I would like to raise an exception, and test that the exception is caught and another function is called before it is re-raised

```
except exception as e:
    car.create_log(car_details)
    raise e
```

The unit test:

```
car = Car()
car.registrations.update = Mock()
car.registrations.update.side_effect = RegistrationError()
car.create_log = Mock()

car.register_car('123123')

car.create_log.assert_called_once()
self.assertRaises(RegistrationError)
```

I can confirm the method throws an error but cannot test that the method `create_log` is called before the error is re-raised.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use `assertRaises`:

```
with self.assertRaises(RegistrationError):
    car.register_car('123123')

car.create_log.assert_called_once()
```

or you can pass it a callable and arguments:

```
self.assertRaises(RegistrationError, car.register_car, '123123')
```